# Tax Set Up For UK Business with USA Site Despatching to EU

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, vat

We have 3 stores operating from one admin panel.   We are a UK based business and we sell Globally.   We have set up all the VAT rules and everything is working as we would expect it to other than the USA site - we also have an AUS site that is working as it should be.

With AUS and USA - any customers who buy from these sites for deliveries to these countries or anywhere else outside the EU Zone we dont have to account for VAT.

If however on the rare occasion someone orders from these sites for delivery to the UK or any other EU Member State we need to account for VAT.   We have configured the tax for AUS and all this works.   We have now tried to apply the same for the USA and we cannot get this to work - is this related in anyway to Magento being a USA platform.   For reference we are using the community edition.   If anyone can help that would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your full tax configuration under System > Configuration > Tax for your US store and your AU store? Your VAT tax rules and rates should apply to all stores, so I'm guessing it's a configuration issue somewhere.

Comment: Hi Jake - happy to but dont think I have the functionality within here to share a screen print

Comment: What I can confirm is each country has been configured using the same configurations yet we are getting different results for USA

Comment: I have started to think there could be a difference in the back end code somewhere as one site was built by one developer and the other by another but no joy there as yet.   I am also looking at catalogue configurations to see whether any issues with this

Comment: I have looked at Tax Jar as a development plugin but would like to understand whether this works for EU Trade or just USA currently.   Im not the developer I am the project manager who commercially looks at what is going to be right both technically and commercially for the site taking into account resources and operational infrastructure.

Comment: TaxJar's extension does [support standard VAT rates in the EU](https://www.taxjar.com/guides/integrations/magento/#international-stores) as well as calculations in the US and Australia. You may need to edit your original question to upload screenshots or use Imgur to provide links within a comment.